# Using jQuery and the HTML5 data property to change background

Tags: jquery, css, html

What I am attempting is to have the background change to a DIV when you roll over it.
I currently have 3 boxes, and each box will have its own background color, before, and after the rollover.

```
.box1 {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box2 {
  background: green;
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.box3 {
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
    <div class="box1" data-bg="black"></div>
    <div class="box2" data-bg="yellow"></div>
    <div class="box3" data-bg="orange"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').hover(function() {
    var myBG = $(this).data('thisbg');
    $(this).css('background', myBG);

           });
        });
```

Comment: Why not do this in pure CSS? Is there some reason the hover BG colours need to be specified in the HTML?

Comment: It's `.data('bg')` and not `.data('thisbg')`

Comment: Why would `.data('thisbg')` access a `data-bg` property? Also, unless you're using the various *other* features of [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), using `data` just as an attribute getter is overkill. Just use `.attr("data-bg")`. `data` is **not** just a shorthand for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('div').hover(function() {
          var myBG = $(this).attr('data-bg');      
          $(this).css('background', myBG);
      });
 });
```

Fiddle http://jsbin.com/febuvefube/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

"myBG" data attribute is bg, not "thisbg"

```
var myBG = $(this).data("bg");
```

Or you can do it as

var myBG = $(this).attr("data-bg");